# Adding new option to select menu

Tags: javascript, html

This is a very simple select bar. Why is it not working?

```
<html>
<form>
    <label>
        <select id="sel1">
            <option> op1 </option>
            <option> op2 </option>
            <option> op3 </option>
        </select>
        <input onclick="s()" type="submit" value=" ok! ">
    </label>
</form>
<script>
    function s(){
        document.getElementById("sel1").innerHTML += "<option> op4 </option>";
    }
</script>
</html>
```

If I want people to add new option, I need to put some variable on it. How can I add php variable instead of op4, op5, etc?

Comment: innerHTML will replace everything in `sel1` element, so you will end up having ony one option there..

Comment: @whatever Not exactly, OP uses `+=`.

Comment: @Vohuman yes right...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30142147/what-is-wrong-with-the-next-sibling-of-the-textarea/30142276#30142276

This thread has nice info on how to use `innerHTML`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an actual `option` element and append it to the `select` element.

```
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.value     = "op4";
option.innerHTML = "op4";

var select = document.getElementById("sel1");
select.appendChild(option);
```

You should probably be using `value` attributes in your options too.

---

> This is the next question. Then if i want people to add new option , i need to put some php variable on it. how can i add php variable instead of op4 , op5 and... options?

No, this has nothing to do with PHP.

```
<input id="option-name">
```

Using the example above, instead of using a fixed `"op4"`, use the value from the input

```
var input = document.getElementById("option-name");

var option = document.createElement("option");
option.value     = input.value;
option.innerHTML = input.value;

var select = document.getElementById("sel1");
select.appendChild(option);
```

Now the input value will be used as the name/value for the new option

Comment: If we consider and add keewnn and vohuman answers to this answer , then this answer is the best. tnx to all.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script>
    function s(){
        var o=new Option();
        o.value="<?php echo $option; ?>";
        o.text="<?php echo $option; ?>";
        var os=document.getElementById("sel1").options;
        os[os.length]=o;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I had an error on first line of function "Var o=new option();" and can you tell me what can do "os" on this code?

Comment: My typo: new **O**ption with a capital O

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
<input onclick="s()" type="submit" value=" ok! ">
```

To this:

```
<input onclick="s()" type="button" value=" ok! ">
```

Using `type="submit"` will result in your form being submitted and thus your page being reloaded. Using `type="button"` prevents this.

Answer (score 1):

What happens is the `form` is submitted and as the `form` element doesn't have `action` attribute the current page is reloaded.

You should listen to `submit` event and prevent the default action of the event using `preventDefault` method of the event object.

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var option = new Option('optionText', 'optionValue');
    document.getElementById("sel1").add(option);
});
```

Another option is using a `button` element with `type` attribute of `button` instead of a submit `input`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally write completed Answer. In 2 ways; The first way is safer than another. first way is :

```
<html>
<form>
    <label>
        <input type="text" id="option-name">
        <select id="sel1">
            <option> Option1 </option>
            <option> Option2 </option>
            <option> Option3 </option>
        </select>
        <input onclick="s()" type="button" value=" Create ! "><br/><br/>
    </label>
</form>
<script>
    function s(){
        var input = document.getElementById("option-name");
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value     = input.value;
        option.innerHTML = input.value;
        var select = document.getElementById("sel1");
        select.appendChild(option);
    }
</script>
</html>
```

That is other guys answer too. But the second way is easier and useful. not safer (I think innerhtml is not so safe for this purpose! but if I wrong , please tell me.)!

```
<html>
<form method="post" action="index.php">
    <label>
        <input type="text" name="txt1">
        <select id="sel1">
            <option> Option1 </option>
            <option> Option2 </option>
            <option> Option3 </option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value=" Create ! ">
    </label>
</form>
<script>
    document.getElementById("sel1").innerHTML += "<option><?php echo $_POST['txt1']; ?></option>";
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @Vohuman . Can you check my second way safety? Is it safe?